# Como converter um array em hash?

Tags: ruby

Eu possuo o seguinte retorno:

```
[{"eh5g4vs84ah84gsdf4a8va"=>"information"}]
```

É um `hash` dentro de um `array`. Eu gostaria de saber como eu retiro esse `Hash` de dentro do `array`?

Ele é o retorno de uma consulta assim:

```
Promotions.no_tab_fields(organization.id, product.class).map do |custom_field|
  campo = { custom_field.hash_field => product.custom_columns[custom_field.hash_field] }
end
```

A minha dúvida é tirar de dentro do array.

Já tentei:

- to_h
- Hash(campo) //campo é o array que tem o hash dentro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O retorno de um `#map` é um array. A estrutura que você tem é um array de hashes.

É só acessar com o índice:

```
resultados = [{"eh5g4vs84ah84gsdf4a8va"=>"information"}]
resultados[0]
#=> {"eh5g4vs84ah84gsdf4a8va"=>"information"}
```

Ou se quiser transformar esse array em um hash só, pode usar `Hash#merge`. Só cuidado para que as chaves dos diferentes hashes não conflitem:

```
[{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }].reduce(:merge)
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Alternativamente:

```
[{"eh5g4vs84ah84gsdf4a8va"=>"information"}].first

hash_dentro_array, restante = *[{"eh5g4vs84ah84gsdf4a8va"=>"information"}]
```

basicamente, você está simplesmente pegando o valor no índice 0 do array, que é um hash. Você faria o mesmo se ele fosse qualquer tipo de valor (inteiro, string, objeto, etc)